# Probability of consecutive disjoint events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

> Let be $A$ and $B$ two disjoint events which represent outcomes of a stochastic experiment. We assume $P(A)+P(B)>0$. Show that if you repeat the experiment, then the probability that $A$ appears before $B$ is given by $\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}$.

---

I don't quite understand how to come up with this solution. In my opinion we have to distinguish between the outcomes of the different stages, i.e. $(A_1,A_2),(A_1,B_2), (B_1,A_2) (B_1,B_2)$. But we have no information about how those events of different stages are related to each other.

Actually we are looking for
$$
P(\{(A_1,B_2)\})=P(A_1\mid A_1\cup B_1)\cdot P(B_2\mid A_1\cap (A_1\cup B_1)).
$$
Rearranging and using the definition of the conditional probability delivers:
$$
\begin{align*}
&P(A_1\mid A_1\cup B_1)P(B_2\mid A_1\cap (A_1\cup B_1))=\frac{P(A_1)}{P(A_1\cup B_1)}\frac{P(B_2\cap A_1)}{P(A_1)}\\
&=\frac{P(A_1\cap B_2)}{P(A_1)+P(B_1)}=\dots\overset{???}{=}\frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}.
\end{align*}
$$
Is there any chance to prove the claim without any further assumptions? Maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You repeat untill you hit something in $A \cup B$ not just twice, if it were twice you have to guarantee that either $A$ or $B$ appears in every try , so in that case you should have:  $P(A \cup B ) = 1 $ , but that is not the case. If you repeat untill you are in $A \cup B$ the chance of getting $A$ is just:

$$ \frac{P(A|A \cup B)}{P(A \cup B)} = \frac{P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)} $$

The way to think about this is that you don't care about other outcomes (not in $A \cup B$) thus the experiment is just modeled by a Bernoulli process in essence, as you truncate everything else.

Comment: I have used conditional probabilties, i.e. under the condition $A\cup B$! So no need to throw until $A$ or $B$ Show up. Also, in your approach you implicitly assume independence among two different throws. We don't know that.

Comment: @Philipp It is reasonable to assume independence between consecutive experiments, but all we need to know is we are told that the probabilities of events $A$ and $B$ are constant for each experiment.

Comment: The way the problem is phrased is that to my understanding the throws are independent and you repeat the process constantly, you can stop when you hit $A$ or $B$ simply because the other outcomes don't matter. Also the fact that you used conditional probabilities just reinforces my point, you are either in $A$ or in $B$. In any case, just post the problem in its original form and if my understanding is incorrect we can work through it. However, I believe that anyone reading it assumes the throws are independent and that you repeat constantly untill $A \cup B$.

Comment: @GrahamKemp, we don't know if events of different experiments are independent. Also, even if we knew that $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ don't change throughout all the experiments it would not provide any information about the conditional probabilities like $P(A_i\mid A_{i-1},B_{i-2})$. In my opinion this problem is not well defined and lacks of further assumptions. Moreover, if we assumed independence then the probability of the event we are looking for would simply be $\frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A)+P(B)}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let the experiment be dice throw. A is that 1 appears; and B is that 2 appears. Let C be the outcome that 3,4,5,6 appear.

You have to repeat the experiment till either one of A or B appears. You may have to do multiple dice throws (may be >2).

Comment: Don't your idea (dice throw) implicitly assumes that $P(A_1\cap B_2)=P(A_1)P(B_2)$ i.e. independence among two stages. We don'know this. Moreover the statement "you have to do multiple dice throws until $A$ or $B$ appear" is represented by the condition $(A_1\cup B_1)$. So I don't understand what exactly you are trying to explain?

Comment: @Philipp  The results of a *single* experiment are disjoint.  The results of *different* experiments are independent.